# Find words and associate to a value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, documentation

I got a list of items with several values validated from a list. Each value is a word which I would like to associate with a number and attribute a score:

[image]

For instance: Michael's evaluation contains Proactive, two Not Technically Capable, and Quick Learner, so according to the Profile/Value table, Michael scored 4.

Here is the URL:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DD2jnS0M1z1f6i7wHImbiiyDcLv-M2vq3fio1sry4Do/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you shared you sheet including your own attempt.

Comment: Just edited and added the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:E12; A16:B26; 2; 0); 0); {1;1;1;1}))
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine, however, if I want to add more lines, the score does not follow. Where in the formula I can edit if I want to add new?

Comment: more rows in your first table - change B2:E12 to B2:E

Comment: more rows in your second table - change A16:B26 to A16:B

Comment: more columns in your first table - change {1;1;1;1} to {1;1;1;1;1}